# Added pe executable section corrupting .text section

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I am trying to add a section to pe executable, when I add the section it is corrupting the memory of the first 40 bytes of the .text section. I wanted to know if anyone knows why my function is corrupting the .text section?

When I check in CFF explorer all the offsets are correct including the new sections. This has happened repeatedly with different files.

Here is the code to create the added section:

```
int addSection(char* sectionName, DWORD size){
int pos = ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
firstSection[pos].VirtualAddress = align((firstSection[pos - 1].VirtualAddress + firstSection[pos - 1].Misc.VirtualSize), ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
firstSection[pos].Misc.VirtualSize = (size);
firstSection[pos].PointerToRawData = align((firstSection[pos - 1].PointerToRawData + firstSection[pos - 1].SizeOfRawData), ntHeader->OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
firstSection[pos].SizeOfRawData = align(size, ntHeader->OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
firstSection[pos].NumberOfLinenumbers = 0;
firstSection[pos].NumberOfRelocations = 0;
firstSection[pos].PointerToLinenumbers = 0;
firstSection[pos].PointerToRelocations = 0;
ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections++;
ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage += align(firstSection[ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections-1].Misc.VirtualSize, ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

add section in Portable Executable file : https://github.com/Ge0/PeTools/tree/master/PeAddSection

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution there is not enough space at the end of section headers to add another section header so its overwriting the section straight after which is .text. Now I need to find out how to increase header space in file so I can add a section header without overflow.